# Implement RxJava with Sync Adapters

Tags: android, rx-java, android-syncadapter, rx-android

I'm trying to use [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) through [RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) and its others librarys as [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle) to update an `Activity` after fetching some data from a `SyncAdapter`. I know how to execute a network call throug a `Service` when it is call from the `Activity`. For example:

```
Observable<String> fetchFromGoogle = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
        try {
            String data = fetchData("http://www.google.com");
            subscriber.onNext(data); // Emit the contents of the URL
            subscriber.onCompleted(); // Nothing more to emit
        }catch(Exception e){
            subscriber.onError(e); // In case there are network errors
        }
    }
});

fetchFromGoogle
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) // Create a new Thread
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // Use the UI thread
.subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
    @Override
    public void call(String s) {
        view.setText(view.getText() + "\n" + s); // Change a View
    }
});
```

The problem is that when using a `SyncAdapter` the `SyncManager` is the responsable to start the `Service` to fetch the data. Therefore I don't know how to create an `Observable` that suscribes on a thread that hasn't been started and that observes on the UI.

I was thinking in creating a `Singleton` `Subject` that my `Activity` can suscribe on, and in the `SyncAdapter` create an `Observable` that emitis an event when it is done (after suscribing the `Singleton` `Subject`).

What could be a better/right solution?

Comment: did you solve that on your own after getting no responses here? what was your solution? thanks

Comment: @homtg not actually on my own. I found this [repository](https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture) about _Clean Architecture_ that really gives some good lights. What I end up doing was to implement the SyncAdapter as you usually would then whenever he syncs it triggers an event using an Event Bus (no rxjava). In the presentation layer there's a presenter which subscribes to this event and it updates the view accordingly executing the appropriate use case through rxjava.